# MS Access - SQL Server does not exist or access denied (Error), Tried Everything

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, connection-string, tcp

I have a MS Access DB front end that connects to SQL Server Express backend. Port 1433 is enabled on the In-Bound server side, TCP/IP is enabled with correct Port, I've tried to include "tcp:" in front of the "Server=", I've included "Port=1433" and have tried multiple connection strings. This error only occurs with certain users that are on a Guest Network. However, other users using different Guest Networks have had success with no issues. I've also tried creating ODBC connection through Administrative Tools using SQL Server and SQL Native Client with no success and TCP/IP Enabled. Using cmd.exe and pinging to the IP is successful. After googling for hours and trying multiple solutions, I am completely stumped! Does anyone have some guidance?

MS Access 2010 (On user end) DSN-Less connection to tables.

```
Dim cns As ADODB.Connection
Set cns = New ADODB.Connection
cns.ConnectionTimeout = 4
cns.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=111.111.111\MYDB;Trusted_Connection=no;Database=MYDB;Uid=UserID;Pwd=Password;"
```

Also tried Driver={SQL Native Client} as well as other drivers and connection strings.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the user was able to connect on a different Wifi connection. Tried disabling firewall and allowing outbound port to 1433 and 1434 UDP. SSMS "Allow remote connections" is also enabled. No other programs are blocking port 1433. Is there a way to determine what the issue is under this particular Wifi connection?

Comment: Did you check if SQL Server Express and Browser services are running? Right click taskbar for Task Manager (or ctrl+alt+delete) and click Services to see.

Comment: Yea, they are running. I tried creating a VPN for users with no luck. Not sure how to bypass the ISP and open port 1433.